# Zoo::Rollmax How to shorten width to prevent errors

Tags: r, zoo

I have 10 days of values, and for each day I want to know the max of the previous 4 days. If there aren't 4 days worth of values, then I want the max of the last 3 days, etc. Code example:

```
set.seed(131)
Index <- 1:10
Val <- c(sample(10, 10, replace = T))
df = data.frame(Index, Val)

dfoo = df %>%
  mutate(Lag1 = lag(Val, 1, default = 0), #get last days value
         Last4Max = rollmax(Lag1, 4, partial = T, fill = 0, align = "right")) #get max of last 4 days
```

This works for all but for day 2/3 since there aren't 4 values in Lag1 (day 1 should be 0/NA because there's no "previous" day).

```
   Index Val Lag1    Last4Max
1      1   3    0        0
2      2   2    3        0
3      3   3    2        0
4      4   4    3        3
5      5   9    4        4
6      6   6    9        9
7      7   6    6        9
8      8   3    6        9
9      9   4    3        9
10    10  10    4        6
```

So `Last4Max` should be 3 for index 2/3, and 0/NA for 1. Is there a way to change the width size to account for having width>rownumbers? My alternative is to create 4 variables for each lag (with default = 0) and then take the max of all 4. I know this would work but it seems clunky, and it'd limit me if I wanted to quickly do max of last 10 days on a bigger dataset.

Thanks

Comment: This is a rare case where a loop might be the better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Note that:

- as per `?rollmax` it does not have a `partial` argument; however, we can use `rollapply` or `rollapplyr` with a `partial` argument and specify `FUN = max`.
- `rollapplyr` (and also `rollmaxr`) with an `r` on the end defaults to `align = "right"` allowing one to avoid writing that argument out
- the `width` argument can specify a one-component list of offsets so to specify that the prior 4 elements are to be used we can specify `width = list(-seq(4))` eliminating the need for a separate lag column.

Putting all these together we get:

```
rollapplyr(Val, list(-seq(4)), max, partial = TRUE, fill = 0)
## [1] 0 3 3 3 4 9 9 9 9 6
```

**2)** Another way to do this is to use a width of 5 but not use the last element when taking the maximum.  In this case we don't need `fill = 0` since it is able to process each component of `Val` leaving nothing to fill.

```
Max <- function(x) if (length(x) > 1) max(head(x, -1)) else 0
rollapplyr(Val, 5, Max, partial = TRUE)
```

**2a)** If we knew that all elements of `Val` were non-negative then we could alternately use this shorter definition for `Max`:

```
Max <- function(x) max(head(x, -1), 0)
```